# Выборка записей из MySQL из 3 таблиц

Tags: массивы, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Помогите раз и навсегда разобраться. Заранее спасибо.
Имеется таблица brands: (Бренды товаров)

```
поле id
поле name
```

Таблица category: (Категории товаров)

```
поле id
поле name
```

Таблица goods: (Сами товары)

```
поле id
поле brand_id
поле category_id
```

Необходимо, чтобы все ТОВАРЫ каждого БРЕНДА выстроились в массив по КАТЕГОРИЯМ, но без повторов. То есть, не просто вывести все товары бренда по категориям, а как бы так:

```
БРЕНД 1 -> Категория 1, Категория 2, Категория 3, Категория 4, Категория 5.
БРЕНД 2 -> Категория 1, Категория 2, Категория 3
БРЕНД 3 -> Категория 4, Категория 5.
```

Допустим состав таблиц такой:
brands:

```
id | name
1 | Бренд 1
2 | Бренд 2
```

category

```
id | name
1 | Категория 1
2 | Категория 2
3 | Категория 3
```

goods

```
id | brand_id | category_id
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 1 | 2
5 | 2 | 1
6 | 2 | 2
7 | 2 | 2
8 | 2 | 3
```

Пример итога:
    Бренд 1: Категория 1, Категория 2
    Бренд 2: Категория 1, Категория 2, Категория 3

Need на PHP...:)
Я так иду к решению. Но оно 1) ужасно; 2) не дошел до конца. 3) черт!

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM brands");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++){
   $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);
   $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE goods.brand_id='".$arr['id']."' LEFT JOIN category ON category.id=goods.cat_id");
}
```

Получается, что нужно два запроса в одном?

Comment: АА, Вы гениальны. Саму схему почти понял, проверю, отпишусь.

Comment: @alexlz: превратите в ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может я чего-то не понял, но почему так не подходит?

```
select distinct b.name, c.name 
from goods g inner join brands b on g.brands_id = b.id
  inner join category c on g.category_id = c.id
order by g.brands_id, g.category_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Если количество категорий ограничено воспользуйтесь:

```
CASE WHEN THEN END
```

Иначе вам поможет `GROUP_CONCAT`, только с таким подходом вам придется парсить в клиенте ваше поле с категориями
[Пример использование `GROUP__CONCAT`](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/comparing-tsql-cross-apply-mysql-groupconcat/280).

в MySQL насколько я знаю `PIVOT UNPIVOT` не поддерживается.